# Exchanging integrals, derivatives and series

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, summation

I need to solve this integral:

$$I = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (-1)^n x^{2n} \arctan(x) dx.$$

Firstly, I know that $f_n(x) = (-1)^n x^{2n} \arctan(x)$ punctually converges to $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{4}\right]$.

Moreover, it converges also uniformly. Indeed:

$$\sup_{x \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{4}\right]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = \sup_{x \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{4}\right]} x^{2n}\arctan{x} = \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{2n}\arctan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \to 0,$$
as $n\to +\infty$.

Then I can exchange the integral and the sum.

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}  \arctan(x)\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n x^{2n} dx.$$

Now, I know that:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = (-1)^nx^{2n},$$

and then:

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}  \arctan(x)\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{d}{dx} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1} dx.$$

For the uniform convergence, I can exchange the sum and the derivative:

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \arctan(x) \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}  dx.$$

It's well known that $$\arctan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$, and then:

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \arctan(x) \frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x)  dx = \arctan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) - \arctan^2(0) = \\
\arctan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right).$$

Is this right?

Comment: After "now I know that..." you take the derivative. But that result does not come back in your next lines, which makes me wonder the necessity of that step. Carefully following your steps I don't see anything wrong in your result, but don't take my word for it. I am not that knowledgeable...

Comment: @imranfat I appreciate your consideration, sir. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slightly shorter way: after permuting the sum and the integral, note that inside the integral you will get $\sum \limits _{n=0} ^\infty (-x^2)^n$ which is a geometric series that sums to $\frac 1 {1+x^2}$, which is precisely the derivative of $\arctan$, therefore you can immediately integrate: $\int \limits _0 ^\frac \pi 4 \frac 1 {1+x^2} \arctan x \Bbb d x = \arctan ^2 x \big| _0 ^\frac \pi 4 = 1$.

Otherwise, yes, your computation is correct.